# Stealing the contents of another application's tree view

Tags: java, swing, treeview, windows-messages

I have an application with a very large TreeView control in Java.  I want to get the contents of the tree control in a list (just strings not a JList) of XPath-like elements of leaves only.  Here's an example
root

```
|-Item1
  |-Item1.1
    |-Item1.1.1 (leaf)
  |-Item1.2 (leaf)
|-Item2
  |-Item2.1 (leaf)
```

Would output:

```
/Item1/Item1.1/Item1.1.1
/Item1/Item1.2
/Item2/Item2.1
```

I don't have any source code or anything handy like that.  Is there I tool I can use to dig into the Window item itself and pull out this data?  I don't mind if there are a few post-processing steps because typing it in by hand is my only other option.

Comment: Are you saying you have a JTree?

Comment: I came up with two possible interpretations of the question and tried to answer both of them.  Hopefully at least one answer will be helpful. :-)

Comment: I assume the application has a JTree, but I don't have direct access to it.  This may require Windows Messages or something ugly like that.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that you have a `TreeModel` (which you can get from a `JTree` using `JTree.getModel()`), then the following code would print out the leaves of the tree in the "/"-separated format that you are looking for:

```
/**
 * Prints the path to each leaf in the given tree to the console as a
 * "/"-separated string.
 * 
 * @param tree
 *          the tree to print
 */
private void printTreeLeaves(TreeModel tree) {
    printTreeLeavesRecursive(tree, tree.getRoot(), new LinkedList<Object>());
}

/**
 * Prints the path to each leaf in the given subtree of the given tree to
 * the console as a "/"-separated string.
 * 
 * @param tree
 *          the tree that is being printed
 * @param node
 *          the root of the subtree to print
 * @param path
 *          the path to the given node
 */
private void printTreeLeavesRecursive(TreeModel tree,
                                      Object node,
                                      List<Object> path) {
    if (tree.getChildCount(node) == 0) {
        for (final Object pathEntry : path) {
            System.out.print("/");
            System.out.print(pathEntry);
        }
        System.out.print("/");
        System.out.println(node);
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < tree.getChildCount(node); i++) {
            final List<Object> nodePath = new LinkedList<Object>(path);
            nodePath.add(node);
            printTreeLeavesRecursive(tree,
                                     tree.getChild(node, i),
                                     nodePath);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, if you didn't just want to print the tree's contents to the console, you could replace the `println` statements with something else, such as output to a file or such as writing or appending to a `Writer` or a `StringBuilder` that is passed to these methods as an additional argument.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm posting a second answer, depending on the interpretation of the question...)

If you already know what to do once you have a `JTree` and you're just trying to find the `JTree` component in an arbitrary `Container` (including any `JComponent`, `Window`, `JFrame`, etc.), then the following code will search the given `Container` and return the first `JTree` it finds (or `null` if no `JTree` can be found):

```
/**
 * Searches the component hierarchy of the given container and returns the
 * first {@link javax.swing.JTree} that it finds.
 * 
 * @param toSearch
 *          the container to search
 * @return the first tree found under the given container, or <code>null</code>
 *         if no {@link javax.swing.JTree} could be found
 */
private JTree findTreeInContainer(Container toSearch) {
    if (toSearch instanceof JTree) {
        return (JTree)toSearch;
    }
    else {
        for (final Component child : toSearch.getComponents()) {
            if (child instanceof Container) {
                JTree result = findTreeInContainer((Container)child);
                if (result != null) {
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```